# CakePHP2 で Contollerに追加したメソッドがViewから実行できない

Tags: cakephp

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。

Viewにて FormHelper::postLink()メソッドを使用しリンクを生成
したのですが、Contorollerの対応するメソッドが実行できず、
トップページに戻ってしまいます。

V**iew記述部**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink('出力', array('action' => 'CsvTest', '?' => $this->request->query)); ?>
```

**Controller記述部**

```
public function CsvTest(){
  // 処理ロジック
}
```

原因や対処方法など、ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけたら非常にありがたいです。

どうぞ、よろしくお願い致します。

<各バージョン>
PHP     5.4.16
CakePHP 2.10.12

※ teratail でも [同じ質問](https://teratail.com/questions/qkkcpqb2fhn8w6) をさせていただいております。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/qkkcpqb2fhn8w6) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)